# Linear transformations and conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation given
>   by \begin{equation*} T(x_1, x_2,...x_n)=(a_1x_1, a_2x_2,...,a_nx_n).
>  \end{equation*} a) Under which conditions on $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$, is T
>   invertible?
>
> b) Assuming the conditions above are satisfied, find $T^{-1}$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Under what conditions can you solve all of the following simultaneously for arbitrary $y_1,...,y_n$?
\begin{eqnarray}
y_1 &=& a_1 x_1 \\
&\vdots& \\
y_n &=& a_n x_n \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Hmm...I guess I know waht you are driving at here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $T$ has the matrix $\mbox{diag}(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $M$ for the linear transformation $T$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}$.

Thus $T$ is invertible iff none of the $a_{i}$ is equal to $0$.  In this case the inverse of $T$ is simply given by
$$T^{-1}(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}) = \left(\frac{x_{1}}{a_{1}},\frac{x_{2}}{a_{2}},\ldots\frac{x_{n}}{a_{n}}\right)$$

Comment: I see. So, how can I find the T^-1?

Comment: I fixed the typo.

Comment: Oh, now it is OK. Thank you Bender!!!!